# How to close the Quick Settings system panel using UIAutomator?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-uiautomator

In my android test, I have opened the quick settings panel using the following code:

```
device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
device.openQuickSettings()
```

How do I now close or slide back the quick settings panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though there is no method to explicitly close it, you can use `UiDevice` object to call `pressBack()` method, on API >= 16. This `Simulates a short press on the BACK button` (The hardware back button on the device) to close the quick settings. With some devices, two `pressBack()`call is required.
Example:

```
//Initialize UiDevice object
var uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())

//Open Quick Settings
uiDevice.openQuickSettings()

//Close the quick settings
uiDevice.pressBack()

/*
* If you will be using this test on multiple devices 
* and don't know if you need to pressBack() twice then,
* You can check for an object with the Description of "Airplane mode"
* Which would mean quickSettings still partly open, so press back button again
*
* var pressAgain = false
* for (uiObj in uiDevice.findObjects(By.descContains("Airplane mode")))
*    pressAgain = true          
*/

//Devices require 2 calls to pressBack()
//if(pressAgain)
//   uiDevice.pressBack()
```